# Pure CSS zoom animation based on timer?

Tags: css

I know I can do a zoom animation in CSS, when hovering a button for example.

But I was wondering if I could make the **zoom animation based on a specific timer**.
Like a **short zoom in and zoom out animation during 0.5s**, which comes back every 5 seconds.

Something like the button on this URL https://www.laboutiquetrend.com/collections/produits/products/epilateur-corporel-2-0 (scroll a bit to make it appear)

[image]

Again, it would help if this is only CSS, since I apply custom CSS on the elements of a theme.

Let me know thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: still haven't figured how I could combinate a quick zoom in and zoom out and then a long delay, but I'm working on it

Comment: The way they did it is by animations, you cab just copy what they did and customize it

Comment: I'd love too, but how can I extract the content of the animation? It popups for barely 0.5s it's too quick to see it in "Edit code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications, it's now pure CSS however it's a bit poor.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #ccc333;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  animation-name: pulse;
  /*animation-fill-mode: both;*/
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: WOW if you've done it all by yourself, a great thanks!! Still would like to know how you could see the original code, it would help for future :) now I will try to adapt to the appropriate selectors, I will put "correct" once I'm done :)

Comment: okay so it works like a charm, I managed to integrate it. I wanted o add delays between 2 animations (around 5 seconds) but I notice the animation-duration property is only for initial display. How could I go around this?

Comment: I don't think you can add delay between animations, with just css. How I got their code ? Devtools and waited for the animation to happen then I caught it

Comment: that works! thank you very much anyway, you were a great help! :)

Comment: With pleasure :)